# Wicket - updating ListView using AJAX and Wicket Model

Tags: java, html, ajax, wicket

I have a :

- Client Class
- ListView
- TextField

I need to populate my ListView in order to form a table:

WORKING CODE:

```
clientModel = new LoadableDetachableModel() {

            @Override
            protected Object load() {

                return Client.getClientListByCompanyName(searchClientInput.getValue());
            }
        };

        searchClientInput.setModel(new Model<String>());

        searchClientInput.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onkeyup") {

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                target.add(clientListViewContainer);
            }
        });

        clientListView = new ListView<Client>(CLIENT_ROW_LIST_ID, clientModel) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<Client> item) {

                Client client = item.getModelObject();

                item.add(new Label(CLIENT_ROW_COMPANY_CNPJ_ID, client.getCompanyName()));
                item.add(new Label(CLIENT_ROW_COMPANY_NAME_ID, client.getCompanyCnpj()));
            }
        };

        clientListViewContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        clientListViewContainer.add(clientListView);

        add(clientListViewContainer);
```

Now, in my HTML, I have a TextField. Whenever an user types something in this TextField, a select will be made in the database with whatever he typed. So for each word, a select is made, and the table needs to be updated. I am guessing I will need to use AJAX and possibly a Model. I'm kind of lost about how I can do this, if someone can provide me examples I would be  very grateful.

EDIT: New code that is throwing exception: `Last cause: Attempt to set model object on null model of component: searchClientForm:searchClientInput`

EDIT 2: Ok so the exception was that my TextField didn't had a model to bind data to. So what I  did was: `searchClientInput.setModel(new Model<String>());`

I also had a problem with the event. Using `onkeydown` was working, but not as intended. I had Company Name 1-4. If I typed Company Name 1, I would need to press one key again so the table would get updated. With `onkeyup` this don't happens. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "A select is made"  Do you mean you want [AutoComplete Text field](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/autocomplete)? Also getting the auto-update after the selection from that is tricky.  To Auto-Update look into `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` and friends.

Comment: Oops, I think I wasn't very clear. I mean a select is made into the database for each letter typed, and the list is updated.

Comment: @Raystorm hey take a look at my update code please. Some exception was thrown and I'm trying to figure it out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give the ListView a LoadableDetachableModel which provides the selected clients matching your TextField's value.

Use an  AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior on your TextField which add a parent of the ListView to the request target (don't forget #setOutputMarkupId().

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what is this event parameter? I tried going to the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior and to the TextField docs but there was nothing about events.

Comment: Hey I think I got it. I'm using the event `onkeydown`. But an exception was thrown, please can you take a look at the updated code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to perform what you want (which is repainting a table/list at each input change --> DB access) is with a DataView and a DataProvider.

A DataView is just like the ListView component except it uses an IDataProvider to get the data you want to present. You are able to implement the DataProvider so it accesses your DB, and you can add restrictions (`where` clauses) to the DataProvider.

*[this is more like pseudo-code]*

```
public final class MyDataProvider<T> extends SortableDataProvider<T> {
// ...
Set filters; 
// filters is the set where the restrictions you want to apply are stored


...
@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator(int first, int count) {
    // DAO (Data Access Object) access to DB
    // ...
    return dao.findByRestrictions(filters).iterator();
}
...
}
```

Now on the ajax event on your *input* component you are able to update the filter being used in the DataProvider, and in the the next repaint of the DataView, the provider will "*pull*" the data matching the restrictions defined in the filter.

Hope it helps. Best regards.

Comment: Hello. I might use this implementation as I will work with pages in the table. However while you're at it, someone said to me that I should actually do all the AJAX and JavaScript stuff in the html part, as using those components in java generate some bad code. Is this true? In a big project will using these components cause me trouble?

Comment: I don't see any problem on using the Ajax that Wicket provides. For me, that is one (between many) great core functionality of Wicket. One does not need to fully know/understand Ajax to fully control it in Wicket. The guys at Wicket did a great job at that. Regarding safety, or performance, I never had serious problems with it. Perhaps you could direct that kind of questions to the developers or ask around in Wicket forums (http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/)